# UITableviewcell animation only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

Here is my `willDisplayCell` animation code I want to animate only once, don't repeat when scroll up the tableview.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIView *cellContentView = [cell contentView];
    CGFloat rotationAngleDegrees = -30;
    CGFloat rotationAngleRadians = rotationAngleDegrees * (M_PI/180);
    CGPoint offsetPositioning = CGPointMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height*4);
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngleRadians, -50.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offsetPositioning.x, offsetPositioning.y, -50.0);
    cellContentView.layer.transform = transform;
    cellContentView.layer.opacity = 0.8;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.95 delay:00 usingSpringWithDamping:0.85 initialSpringVelocity:0.8 options:0 animations:^{
        cellContentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        cellContentView.layer.opacity = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

    }
```

Comment: You will probably need to keep track of whether a cell has been displayed previously in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set a Boolean on your cell object.

Comment: I can't understand Paulw11 . can you please tell me how to do..

Comment: Simply create an flag which hold initial value as 0 in viewdidload. Check if condition before animation start, when animation done make flag as 1. It will solve your problem. No need to change any other logic at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want any of your code to run only once, you can use dipatch_once. This will make sure that this code is run only once in life span of parent object. You can put that code inside dispatch_async if that code is being run from somewhere other than tableview's event handlers.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
           //Your animation code.
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate each cell only once each cell has to know that it animated itself and it shouldn't again. Easiest way to achieve that is to give the cell `BOOL` variable called `animated` to determine whether if or not the cell has already animated.

#### Create custom cell class

Create new Cocoa Class called for example CustomCell. It should subclass the `UITableViewCell`.

Inside `CustomCell.h` declare a BOOL property called animated:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL animated;
```

If you are using storyboards like me, remember to also update the class of a cell in storyboard editor, just like you do when you are creating new view controllers

That's it here.

#### Modify View Controller

Now you should import your new class and swap `(UITableViewCell *)` with `(CustomCell *)` in your tableViews delegate methods.

In `willDisplayCell:` add necessary logic, it will look like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(!cell.animated){ //added

        cell.animated = YES;  //added    

        UIView *cellContentView = [cell contentView];
        CGFloat rotationAngleDegrees = -30;
        CGFloat rotationAngleRadians = rotationAngleDegrees * (M_PI/180);
        CGPoint offsetPositioning = CGPointMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height*4);
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngleRadians, -50.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offsetPositioning.x, offsetPositioning.y, -50.0);
        cellContentView.layer.transform = transform;
        cellContentView.layer.opacity = 0.8;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.95 delay:00 usingSpringWithDamping:0.85 initialSpringVelocity:0.8 options:0 animations:^{
            cellContentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
            cellContentView.layer.opacity = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

    }
```

And this is it. Hope it works for you

Comment: Do you have the  swift 3 version of this?