# willDisplay not being called when custom cell class is passed in as parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a tableview cell animation that happens only once (until user swipes up to refresh the table) without relying on an array specific to the VC. I want to be able to just implement the change to dozens of VCs...but I'm stuck.

I thought I'd follow the advice in this thread: [UITableviewcell animation only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203124/uitableviewcell-animation-only-once). It says to add a boolean in the custom cell declaration and to just check for that in the willDisplay pre-animation, but I can't access the bool because the function passes in a UItableviewcell as default. When I change that to be the custom cell class, it runs, but the function is no longer called. Any thoughts?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: CustomCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //If transactionPage is set to -1, it's because we've reached the end of the transactions
        if transactionPage != -1 && indexPath.row == (tableData.rows(inSection: indexPath.section).count) - 1 {
            loadMoreTransactions()
        }

        if !cell.alreadyAnimated {
            cell.alpha = 0

            //Slide from bottom
            let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)

            cell.layer.transform = transform

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
                cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            })

            cell.alreadyAnimated = true;
        }
    }
```

the class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK: Properties

    var alreadyAnimated = false;

    var transaction: CustomTransaction! {
        didSet {
            descriptionLabel.text = transaction.desc
            dateLabel.text = format.string(fromOptional: transaction.date)
            amountLabel.text = transaction.getAmountString()
            amountLabel.textColor = (transaction.amount < 0.0) ? .byuRed : .byuGreen
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I can see is that in the protocol declaration of the `UITableViewDelegate` you must change the `..., willDisplay cell: CustomCell,...` for a `...willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell`, and cast the cell to your custom class to be able to access its properties:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //If transactionPage is set to -1, it's because we've reached the end of the transactions
    if transactionPage != -1 && indexPath.row == (tableData.rows(inSection: indexPath.section).count) - 1 {
        loadMoreTransactions()
    }

    if let cell = cell as? CustomCell, !cell.alreadyAnimated {
        cell.alpha = 0

        //Slide from bottom
        let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 200, 0)

        cell.layer.transform = transform

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        })

        cell.alreadyAnimated = true;
    }
}
```

Because the name of the method is different, the system tries to call a not declared method in your class an that why your code is not executed.

Comment: so when it comes to any protocol functions, it's best to implement them exactly as stated and just cast things when we need specific access? That makes sense

Comment: the code works! But now it's not applying the animation to every cell as they appear, but applies to them all at once. Also, what would be the best way to reset the alreadyAnimated value upon tableview refresh? Is iterating the only way

Comment: Yes, any protocol function must be implemented exactly as they are declared and after you should cast the variables if you need it. The animation is applied to all cells at the first time the tableview is reloaded, right? But when you scroll you can see the new cells animating?... The best way of resetting could be different for every implementation, because I suppose your are reusing (`tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:...`) the cells and that causes many problems. So, for me, I would save in an array the indexPath of the already animated cells and for resseting only `removeAll()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the UITableViewCell to your CustomCell class:

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let customCell = cell as? CustomCell {

        // your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: CustomCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {...}
```

... this is just declaring new method, you need to use `UITableViewDelegate`'s method with parameters which was declared with (so you need to keep `UITableViewCell` type for parameter `cell`)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {...}
```

then inside method you can get reference to your custom table view cell subclass by **downcasting** `cell`

```
if let customCell = cell as? CustomCell {
    ...
}
```